# Word for sound made by classical music

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word that can be used in the following sentence:

“During the performances, the streets _____ with the music.”

I’ve considered “tinkled”, but it’s too soft for my liking.

Comment: Classical music has a wide range of sounds (from solo piano thru string trios and quartets, all the way up to full orchestras). I very much doubt you'll find a single word to cover it all.

Answer (score 1):

You might choose a simple term without connotations, such as "*resound*".

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/resound?q=resound)) ​[intransitive] **resound** (through something) (of a sound, voice, etc.) to fill a place with sound
> ♦ Laughter resounded through the house.

- During the performances, the streets resounded with the music.

To denote the force with which the music impinges upon the ambience of the street, you might used "*echoe with*".

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/echo_1?q=echo)) **echo to/with something**  to send back and repeat a sound; to be full of a sound
> ♦ The street echoed with the cries of children.

- During the performances, the streets echoed with the music.